# Lost Clear Catalog Images and Javascript/CSS Cache button in Backend. Magento CE 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, cache, backend

The other day I was just restoring a backup on my website hosting servivce when I accedintally deleted a magento folder via SSH.

Everything started working after the backup was restored, the store was functioning properly until I noticed a thing.

The Clear CSS/JS Cache button was not there, and neither was the Clear Catalog Images Cache button present.
Please help!

[image: Store Backend Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are under `Additional Cache Management`, which comes from this file `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/cache/additional.phtml`

Make sure you have the above file with code intact, and also the layout file `app/design/adminhtml//default/default/layout/admin.xml` with below fragment of code inside:

```
<adminhtml_cache_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="adminhtml/cache" name="cache"></block>
            <block type="adminhtml/cache_additional" name="cache.additional" template="system/cache/additional.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_cache_index>
```

Comment: YEAH! additional.phtml wasn't there, I wonder how it could've gotten deleted. Anyway, I found a copy of it online and added it, and its there now! Thanks very much. Do you have any idea why it was deleted? Is there anything else that might have gone missing?

Comment: You said the backup was restored to bring your site back. Seems that file was not backed up during backup process. Maybe error logs can tell what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved issue.
I have had same issue.

I do not know for what reason this folder cache was empty :

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/cache/additional.phtml

without three file : addional.phtml - edit.phtml and notifications.phtml.

I have added this files and is all ok now.

Regards
Roberto

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, for some reason all files under **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/system/cache** where deleted. Just copied from another installation and all is fine.